# Rails associations not inserting nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

The nested body attribute isn't being inserted although its specified in the form. I'm receiving an "Unpermitted parameter: :message" error, although the tickets model accepts nested attributes for :message. The tickets controller is also permitting message_attributes.

```
Processing by TicketsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tTOKOw/q0H8gXyEnaEK8lmwZUAoMsI4QQAt4VTwG8QdtQNZtf8Yj7N6Z0VR6MZbvoUARzp7DG60dI5RuKtP8Fw==", "ticket"=>{"category"=>"Miscellaneous - Project", "deadline"=>"2019-01-13", "message"=>{"body"=>"sdf"}}, "button"=>""}
Unpermitted parameter: :message
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:32
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
↳ app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:32
Ticket Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO `tickets` (`category`, `deadline`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Miscellaneous - Project', '2019-01-13', '2019-01-14 00:45:52', '2019-01-14 00:45:52')
↳ app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:32
Message Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `messages` (`user_id`, `ticket_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 62, '2019-01-14 00:45:52', '2019-01-14 00:45:52')
↳ app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:32
(116.8ms)  ROLLBACK
↳ app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:32
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 159ms (ActiveRecord: 120.3ms)



ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (Mysql2::Error: Field 'body' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `messages` (`user_id`, `ticket_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 62, '2019-01-14 00:45:52', '2019-01-14 00:45:52')):

app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:32:in `block in create'
app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:31:in `create'
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form.fields_for @ticket.message do |message_form| %>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <%= message_form.label :body %>
    <%= message_form.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :trackable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :messages, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :tickets, through: :messages
end
```

ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :message, inverse_of: :ticket
  has_many :messages, inverse_of: :ticket
  has_many :users, through: :messages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :message
end
```

message.rb

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :messages
  belongs_to :ticket, inverse_of: :message
  belongs_to :ticket, inverse_of: :messages
  validates_presence_of :user, :ticket
end
```

tickets_controller.rb

```
def new
  @ticket = Ticket.new
  @ticket.build_message
end

def create
  @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
  @ticket.build_message(:user_id => current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @ticket.save
      format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ticket }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:category, :deadline, :status, message_attributes: [:body])
  end
```

Comment: You did not whitelist message params on tickets controller

Comment: @Catmal Do you mean with params.require(:ticket).permit(:category, :deadline, :status, :message, message_attributes: [:body])? That still doesn't work and reports the same error.

Comment: remove @ticket.build_message(:user_id => current_user.id) and add @ticket.message.user_id = current_user.id.

Comment: You can't have has_one and has_many messages at the same time. If you really need it, you should rename the association and add corresponding additional `_id` field to the Message model

Answer (score 1):

First you need to rectify your associations.

Having both a `has_one :message` and `has_many :messages` is just plain confusing and will most likely not work the way you have intended.

Of particular concern is:

```
belongs_to :ticket, inverse_of: :message
belongs_to :ticket, inverse_of: :messages
```

What do you think this code does? If you guessed that it creates two associations then you are wrong. When you have two associations with the same name the later association overwrites the former.

I would suggest you axe the `has_one` association:

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
  has_many :users, through: :messages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ticket
  validates_presence_of :user, :ticket
end
```

If you later want to add a separate association to the latest message (or the first message) for eager loading you want to place the foreign key column on the tickets table and use `belongs_to`.

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :latest_message
  has_many :messages, after_add: :update_latest_message!
  has_many :users, through: :messages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages

  private
  def update_latest_message!(msg)
    self.update!(latest_message: msg)
  end
end
```

**However** this optimization only makes sense if you have a huge amount of messages and need to be able to eager load only the latest. I would leave it for later. *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*.

As to why your code is currently failing you should take a look at the params:

```
{  "utf8"=>"✓", ... 
   "ticket"=>{ 
      "category"=>"Miscellaneous - Project", 
      "deadline"=>"2019-01-13", 
      "message"=>{"body"=>"sdf"}}, # should be messages_attributes
      "button"=>""
    }
}
```

You need to setup the form as:

```
<%= form.fields_for :messages do |message_form| %>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <%= message_form.label :body %>
      <%= message_form.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And seed it in the controller:

```
def new
  @ticket = Ticket.new
  @ticket.messages.new # seed the form
end
```

Even if the user is only creating one message at a time you still want to use the messages association.

Comment: made your suggested changes and Ticket#show still works as expected yet the Ticket#new fails to load with error "undefined method `body' for #<Message::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f3c9278f188>
". I tried to debug it via the console and I can set all the attributes for ticket yet things like "@ticket.messages.user_id = 1" fail with "NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id=' for #<Message::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f5b607aabf8>)". I see it thinks its a method and not an attribute.

Comment: My bad, it should of course be `form.fields_for :messages`.

Comment: I made the change and it worked and altered Ticket#create with
      def create
        @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
        @ticket.messages.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
Yet I'm now receiving an error saving the form because Messages user must exist and can't be blank. I assume it isn't setting it as I expected with build.